# Issue when using RxBleClient for scanning BLE devices which are in the background

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, rxandroidble

I am scanning BLE devices which are created by iOS device. Then I connect to specific service and read specific characteristic. It works perfect when iOS app which has GATT service is in the foreground. But when hide iOS server app, Android client stops detect BLE GATT devices.

```
public static ScanFilter[] getFilters(UUID serviceUuid) {
   ...
    filters.add(new ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(new ParcelUuid(serviceUuid)).build());
    return filters.toArray(new ScanFilter[filters.size()]);
}
public static ScanSettings getScanSettings() {
    return new ScanSettings.Builder()
            .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY) // change if needed
            .setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES) // change if needed
            .build();
}
```

[BLE Scanner app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.macdom.ble.blescanner) successfully sees hidden GATT server

**Updates**
Here is filters code part

```
public final class ScannerUtil {
public static final List<UUID> BEACON_UUUIDs = Arrays.asList(
...........

        UUID.fromString("a8427a96-70bd-4a7e-9008-6e5c3d445a2b"));


public static ScanSettings getScanSettings() {
    return new ScanSettings.Builder()
            .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_BALANCED) // change if needed
            .setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES) // change if needed
            .build();
}

public static ScanFilter[] getFilters(UUID serviceUuid) {
    List<ScanFilter> filters = Stream.of(BEACON_UUUIDs)
            .map(iBeaconScanFilter::setScanFilter)
            .collect(toList());
    filters.add(new ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(new ParcelUuid(serviceUuid)).build());
    return filters.toArray(new ScanFilter[filters.size()]);
}
```

}

Full scanner class code is below:

```
public class BLEGlobalScanner {
    private final ScannerConfiguration configuration;
    private final Context context;
    private final RxBleClient rxBleClient;
    private final Map<String, String> devicesMap = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<String, DeviceApoloBeacon> beaconsMap = new HashMap<>();
    private final ScanFilter[] scanFilter;
public BLEGlobalScanner(ScannerConfiguration configuration, Context context) {
    this.configuration = configuration;
    this.context = context;
    this.rxBleClient = RxBleClient.create(context);
    this.scanFilter = getFilters(configuration.beacons(), configuration.gattServer().server());
}

public Observable<BluetoothDeviceApolo> start() {
    return bluetoothEnableObservable(context).switchMap(aBoolean -> startScanner())
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(Optional::get);
}

private Observable<Optional<BluetoothDeviceApolo>> startScanner() {
    return rxBleClient.scanBleDevices(getScanSettings(), scanFilter)
            .buffer(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .flatMap(rxBleDevices -> Observable.from(rxBleDevices)
                    .distinct(scanResult -> scanResult.getBleDevice().getMacAddress())
                    .concatMap(this::handleDevices)
                    .map(Optional::of))
            .observeOn(mainThread())
            .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {
                Timber.e(throwable, "startScanner");
                return Observable.just(Optional.empty());
            })
            .onExceptionResumeNext(Observable.just(Optional.empty()))
            .retry();
}

private Observable<BluetoothDeviceApolo> handleDevices(ScanResult scanResult) {
    if (beaconsMap.containsKey(scanResult.getBleDevice().getMacAddress())) {
        return Observable.fromCallable(() -> beaconsMap.get(scanResult.getBleDevice().getMacAddress()))
                .map(beacon -> beacon.toBuilder()
                        .lastSeen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        .rssi(scanResult.getRssi())
                        .build());
    } else {
        return handleBeacon(scanResult)
                .map(device -> (BluetoothDeviceApolo) device)
                .switchIfEmpty(
                        handleDevice(scanResult).map(deviceApolo -> (BluetoothDeviceApolo) deviceApolo)
                );
    }
}

private Observable<DeviceApoloBeacon> handleBeacon(ScanResult scanResult) {
    return Observable.fromCallable(() -> scanResult.getScanRecord().getManufacturerSpecificData(COMPANY_ID_APPLE))
            .filter(bytes -> bytes != null)
            .filter(bytes -> DeviceApoloBeacon.requiredManufactureSize == bytes.length)
            .map(bytes -> DeviceApoloBeacon.builder()
                    .manufacturedData(bytes)
                    .lastSeen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .rssi(scanResult.getRssi())
                    .build())
            .filter(beacon -> configuration.beacons().contains(beacon.uuuid()))
            .doOnNext(beacon -> beaconsMap.put(scanResult.getBleDevice().getMacAddress(), beacon));
}


private Observable<DeviceApolo> handleDevice(ScanResult scanResult) {
    final RxBleDevice rxBleDevice = scanResult.getBleDevice();
    if (devicesMap.containsKey(rxBleDevice.getMacAddress())) {
        return Observable.fromCallable(() -> devicesMap.get(rxBleDevice.getMacAddress()))
                .timestamp()
                .map(deviceStr -> DeviceApolo.create(deviceStr.getValue(), deviceStr.getTimestampMillis(), scanResult.getRssi()));
    } else {
        return readCharacteristic(rxBleDevice, scanResult.getRssi());
    }
}

private Observable<DeviceApolo> readCharacteristic(RxBleDevice rxBleDevice, final int rssi) {
    return rxBleDevice.establishConnection(false)
            .compose(new ConnectionSharingAdapter())
            .switchMap(rxBleConnection -> rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(configuration.gattServer().characteristic()))
            .map(String::new)
            .doOnNext(s -> devicesMap.put(rxBleDevice.getMacAddress(), s))
            .timestamp()
            .map(deviceStr -> DeviceApolo.create(deviceStr.getValue(), deviceStr.getTimestampMillis(), rssi))
            .retry();
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `when hide iOS server app`?

Comment: That means - when iOS application whitch creates GATT server goes to background

Comment: Assuming that `Android client stops detect BLE GATT devices` means that it does not emit the device when scanning—are you sure that the `BLE Scanner app` does not simply cache the scan results from the time the iOS app was in foreground?

Comment: No, because when iOS backs from background to foreground rx scanner again detects it

Comment: Could you give more info about all the `ScanFilter`s you use and what is the exact flow which you subscribe to?

Comment: There is still lack of information of what is happening. Could you show the full chain of `Observable` that you `.subscribe()` to? Logs could also help.

Comment: @DariuszSeweryn I added full scanner's class code

Comment: I have an idea- before I will post the answer- does switching BT adapter off/on fix the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help

Comment: Could you set `RxBleLog.setLogLevel(RxBleLog.VERBOSE)` and post the logcat output?

Comment: What tags do you want to see?

Comment: Mostly what devices are being scanned and what operations are being executed by the library

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UpMW1ve6RyseJih6hDOLufsn46VoPCed
I dropped there log file. Please take a look at it. Looks like device are found but delay becomes longer

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code nor there is an issue with the `RxAndroidBle`. The peripheral you are scanning for [is discovered eventually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47075059/issue-when-using-rxbleclient-for-scanning-ble-devices-which-are-in-the-backgroun?noredirect=1#comment83132991_47075059).

What you are experiencing is the intended behaviour of iOS app in the background mode—search for `The bluetooth-peripheral Background Execution Mode` on [the official reference site](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html).

The reference states:

> If all apps that are advertising are in the background, the frequency at which your peripheral device sends advertising packets may decrease.

If you intend to use the iOS application as the peripheral then there is not much you can do (check the documentation). Alternatively you can check if you can implement your peripheral on a different hardware (I do not know your exact use-case—but it is not the point of this question).

Best Regards